# Allowing all access to robots.txt in nginx?

Tags: nginx, robots.txt

I have a website with what I think is an uncomplicated setup. In my main `location / {...}` block, I have a bunch of `deny` directives for specific IP addresses that seem to be malicious in some way. I would like to add a block to allow anyone to reach my `robots.txt` file (i.e., even the people who are blocked with a `deny` directive), but I can't get this to work.

I tried to add, at the same level as the main `location / {}` block, the block `location = /robots.txt { allow all; }`, but when I restart nginx, *no one* can reach robots.txt; everyone gets a 404, which seems odd—if I screwed something up, I'd think people would just get their access denied, not a statement that the file doesn't exist.

What's the correct way to do this?

Edit: It seems pointless to show most of the code, as it feels clearly irrelevant, but the gist is:

```
location / {
    deny 1.2.3.4;
    deny 5.6.7.8;
    # etc.
    proxy_pass http://something/;
    # other proxy stuff here
}

location /static {
    alias /path/to/static/files;
}

# If this is here, going to http://example.com/robots.txt returns 404 for everyone
# If it's commented out, everyone can see it
# (except for 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8, in the deny directive above:
# they get a 403. I want them to be able to see it.)
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
}
```

Comment: Edited to add more code.

Comment: [The rules are checked in sequence until the first match is found](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html), unfortunately these docs do not tell what the default is, when no rules match....., so I would add a `allow all`, after you defined all `deny ...` stuff, in the `location / {}` section.

Comment: The `allow all` is unnecessary, as that is the default, but you are missing a `root` statement to tell Nginx where the `robots.txt` file is in the file system.

Comment: Ah. Hmm. I think I know what's going on, but not what to do about it.

Comment: The robots.txt file doesn't actually exist on the filesystem; it's generated dynamically from the database by my app server. There, I match all the routes and deal with them as necessary; most of them are things like `/view/123`. This one matches `/robots.txt` exactly. But nginx is basically sending everything to the app server, and there is no actual file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting everything from backend (the `proxy_pass http://something/;`), you have to repeat it in your `robots.txt` location. Without it, NGINX will try to find it on the filesystem, and of course, return 404.

Should be:

```
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    proxy_pass http://something/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes a huge amount of sense! I'm having trouble getting it to work because for some reason the backend isn't processing it correctly; trying to debug this, but I'm sure you're right. Will update.